# Why asp.net C# Decimal type doesn't get cents?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, decimal

I have a MySQL database with a column Amount type Decimal(10,2).
I use LINQ to insert a record into the database.

```
myTable table = new myTable();
int intAmount = 106564; // I received the data in this format. It is $1,065.64
myTable.Amount = (intAmount / 100); // Why it sets the value to 1065 instead of 1065.64?
```

Does C# Decimal doesn't support decimal values?!?

Comment: Both numbers are integers and thus integer arithmetic is applied. Use  `(intAmount / 100.0M)`;

Comment: Still same problem using 100.0M

Comment: I believe it is not duplicated because my issue is with Decimal, not float

Comment: It's the same issue, decimal or float doesn't matter.

Comment: What is the datatype of `myTable.Amount`? The solution of using 100.0઼M should work. https://dotnetfiddle.net/EaULRr